# Joomla upload button on component toolbar

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, jtoolbar

In my custom component, I am using the following code to bring the Media Manager popup:

```
JToolBarHelper::media_manager('directory', 'Upload');
```

"directory" obviously sets the default directory that will appear when the button is clicked, which it does, but when I go to upload an image, it uploads to the standard `"images"` folder rather than `images/directory`.

I have looked around Google and the majority of pages say that it was a bug in Joomla 1.5 which I assume was fixed in Joomla 2.5. Is there another way to get the default directory working?

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2477186 . Also the Joomla 1.5 bug was fixed in 1.5.15 so it definitely shouldn't be an issue in 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media_manager invokes with folder= and the directory you passed. But it expects the path below your images folder.

So if your folder is

```
/images/uploaddir
```

you would invoke it with

```
JToolBarHelper::media_manager('uploaddir', 'Upload');
```